# What's the idiomatic way to manage reference counts during Obj-C initializers?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, idioms

I'm learning Objective-C. In my first non-trivial project I've run into a question about how to best handle resources passed to the initializer, compared to the default initializer. My class has a retained resource, `engine`, which can be set manually after creation, or during initialization explicitly, or during initialization by default:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        id e = [[XorShiftEngine alloc] init];
        [self setEngine: e];
        [e release];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithEngine:(NSObject <RandEngine> *)e {
    if ((self = [super init]))
        [self setEngine: e];
    return self;
}

- (id)setEngine:(NSObject <RandEngine> *)newEngine {
    [newEngine retain];
    [engine release];
    engine = newEngine;
    // Some other stuff which needs to happen on changing the engine.
    return engine;
}
```

The default initializer, in particular, seems very ugly to me, interleaving code relevant to the self, then the member, then self again, then the member again, and naming the object solely to be able to release it later. It also violates the designated initializer idiom.

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this, without using autorelease pools?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with autorelease pools?

Comment: You'll also want to avoid lots of activity triggered by directly calling the `set*:` methods;  it'll make refactoring and optimization less difficult.

Comment: @Tamás: It seems the wrong approach. I am not using the engine as a temporary variable; it is long-lived, and owned by the implementation shown here.

Comment: Note also that calling the setters from within your `init` methods can be rife with danger in that the object's initialization means that the object is not yet fully setup.  You'll incur unpleasant dependencies that'll make sub-classing significantly harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (id)init {
    id e = [[XorShiftEngine alloc] init];
    self = [self initWithEngine: e];
    [e release];
    return self;
}

// designated initializer
- (id)initWithEngine:(NSObject <RandEngine> *)e {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        engine = [e retain];
        // engine initialization stuff
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)setEngine:(NSObject <RandEngine> *)newEngine {
    [newEngine retain];
    [engine release];
    engine = newEngine;
    // Some other stuff which needs to happen on changing the engine.
    return engine;
}
```

You've done basically the right thing. The only thing I would change is directly assigning the variable and retaining it rather than calling the setter in the init method.

Apple recommends not calling property setters/getters in the init and dealloc methods (I'm assuming you've declared a retain property and are just overriding the setter).

If you have engine customization code that needs to happen the first time the engine is set in the initializer as well as whenever it is changed, then you should refactor this out into a separate method.

Comment: Is there a standard naming convention for such refactors? `engineWasSet`?

Comment: +1, especially for the note about not using setters inside of `init`.

Answer (score 3):

```
- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialization here
    }
    return self;
}
```

If you have "cover initializers", they should follow the same pattern:

```
- initWithBob:(Bob*)aBob
{
   self = [self init];
   if ( self != nil ) {
       ... deal with aBob here ...
   }
   return self;
}
```

This is also a good example of why it is wise to avoid multiple initializers on a class.  It can be a pain to keep track and makes subclassing more tedious and error prone.   Better to have one initializer and multiple subclasses or have a single initializer and allow the instances to be configured after the fact.

I.e. instead of `initWithBob:`, have `@property(retain) Bob* bob;` that can be called after `init` as needed.   Limiting initializers to required state is a good rule of thumb.

---

Assuming you are declaring a Car class, I'd do something like:

```
@interface Car:NSObject
+ car;
+ carWithEngine:(Engine*)anEngine;
- initWithEngine:(Engine*)anEngine;
@end
```

The implementations should be obvious;  `car` creates a default engine and calls `alloc/initWithEngine:/autorelease`.

That gives you a single initializer, making sub-classing dead simple obvious.

Comment: That would actually make the default initializer even longer and more interleaved. It also makes the designated initialization idiom fail.

Comment: Yes, but you *must* call the initializer of the superclass in your own initializer, so there is no way of avoiding it.

Comment: Downvoted for recommending that you follow the well documented patterns? :)  Initializers are a special case -- one of the few -- see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html

Comment: @Tamás: But I _am_ calling the superclass in my own initializer, if I called the superclass in two different ways I only make it harder to override my messages and I am forced to repeat my logic (which granted, is only one line right now) in two places.

Comment: @Joe: Ah, okay. Anyway, the idiomatic way is the one where you make ``[self init]`` call ``[super init]`` and make other initializers call ``[self init]`` first before setting up their own stuff. Unless creating an ``XorShiftEngine`` is a particularly tedious and time consuming task, I wouldn't worry about creating an ``XorShiftEngine`` in ``[self init]`` that just gets overwritten immediately by the specialized initializers later.

Comment: @bbum: I've updated the post to use your suggested idiom to show how it (at least by itself) does not help anything.

Comment: @bbum: Having an engine is in fact required; if the idiomatic way to do this is to make a heap object and immediately throw it out, I guess that's the idiomatic way, but it certainly doesn't endear me to the language in any way. :/

Comment: @Joe Wreschnig, you're **not** throwing out the engine that you create in -init. You're passing it into -initWithEngine:, where it will be retained. All you're doing by releasing the engine that you create in -init is giving up -init's interest in/ownership of the engine. Now, it _could_ be that -initWithEngine: will copy that object or otherwise not be interested in the engine that you pass in, but from the point of view of -init you don't care about that. (Whether you're endeared to the language or not is your own issue to work out.)

Comment: @Joe: your update to `init` doesn't make any sense. You shouldn't assign `self` to the result of `setIvar:`. Setter methods don't usually return anything; they just set the ivar, managing memory as necessary. Your statement about a heap object seems to indicate a misunderstanding of the memory management. If, in your class here, you allocate an `Engine` object and then also retain it (creating two "claims" on the engine), you must release it once or you will end up with a leak. You're not creating something and immediately throwing it away; you're just counting references.

Comment: @Josh: Sorry, that was a leftover from the previous code (SO is far more forgiving than a compiler). The comment about creating and immediately throwing away was in reference to Tamás's statement "I wouldn't worry about creating an XorShiftEngine in [self init] that just gets overwritten immediately by the specialized initializers later." I am aware that the current code does not throw anything out.

Comment: @Joe: I missed that comment by Tamás. He has it backwards. All initializers, including plain `init`, should call through to the "designated initializer", which is usually the one with the most arguments. The designated initializer is the only one which should call `[super init]`. So, `init` should simply return the result of passing a default value to `initWithEngine:`, which should return the result of passing a default value to `initWithEngine:andFoo:`, etc., the last one in the chain being the designated initializer. As bbum said, though, lots of initializers is usually not the right way.

Comment: @Joe: See "Multiple Initializers" in the ["Initializing Objects" chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW55) of the Cocoa Fundamentals guide.

Comment: @Josh: I have read that part of Apple's guidelines, which is why I am surprised both Tamás and bblum are telling me otherwise. (I don't consider two initializers a lot.)

Comment: @Joe: Huh, I just skimmed bbum's code earlier. I think the `[self init]` in the `initWithBob:` may be a typo -- should be `[super init]`. I'd be interested to hear the reasons if it's not.

Comment: Even if it is `[super init]` that still breaks the designated initializer pattern by having two ways to get to the superclass. (Or, if he changes regular `init` to keep the idiom working, his `init` would look exactly like mine did pre-edit.)

Comment: Nope -- it really should be `[self init]` and, yes, it is horribly confusing and fragile to use a pattern like that.  In any case, if you have multiple initializers, one of 'em should be designated, the rest should call through it, and you have to have a blazing ALL SUBCLASSERS MUST OVERRIDE THIS AND ONLY THIS INITIALIZER in your header and docs.

Comment: @bbum: `init` for my designated initializer either leaves the object in an unusable state or requires creating and immediately throwing out a heap object. Is this really your best-practice recommendation? (And if so, which?)

Comment: If your `init` leaves the object in an unusable state and can't be used, why have it at all?

Comment: @bbum: Your last comment ("it really should be `[self init]`") does not square with the doc you linked to above. Are we talking about multiple different cases here? A designated initializer must call the superclass's designated initializer. The subclass's other initializers should call its own D.I. If a designated initializer `initWithIvar:` calls `[self init]`, that makes a circularity.

Comment: My example considered `init` to be the DI and `initWithEngine:` to be the "cover" initializer. In hindsight, backwards from what you originally wrote?  Thus, the call to `init` in that case is correct.  But, yes, it can easily lead to circularities when subclassing even when used correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about `e` in `-init`? I don't see the problem there... you create an object, you use it, you release it. That's the usual and correct pattern for creating and using objects. If you're unhappy with that, though, you could instead have `-init` pass nil into `-initWithEngine:` and have `-initWithEngine:` create the engine if none is provided.

People don't usually talk about a "default initializer" so much as a "designated initializer." The designated initializer is the one that all the other initializers call -- it's often one that allows for the most customization. In this case, `-initWithEngine:` is your designated initializer.